# ffmpeg.win10 nuget package documentation

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, win-universal-app, nuget-package

This is a 'nuget' package for ffmpeg for windows 10 with zero dependencies. But there is no documentation for how to use it? Where can I find documentation to use this package? P.S I have tried the ffmpegIntrop samples for windows 10, tried to build it and it has infinite compile errors. Why isn't a straight forward library for 'ffmpeg' to use on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/) site you can find compilation instructions, sample applications and a link to the [GitHub website](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop) with more information